# How to extract the data from highstock chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Assume that I have a sample highstock chart like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) in the website. I was wondering whether it is possible to extract the data from the chart alone (i.e. chart is created by the third person and the data used for the chart is not accessible to others).

```
<img src="http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line">
```

Comment: The data used to generate the chart is loaded with an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request. You can view it here:http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=? .... you could use a file input so the user could add his own data.

Comment: Here, you can view it. But, there are websites where the data are not visible to user. My goal is to extract the data when only you are given the chart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep. Each chart is stored within HighChart's `Highcharts.charts` array. On the page you've linked that currently contains the one chart:

```
Highcharts.charts
-> [ z.Chart ]
```

This is an object containing all the data within that chart. We can view it by picking it from the `Highcharts.charts` array index (`0` in this case):

```
Highcharts.charts[0]
-> z.Chart { ... }
```

This contains all the information you'd need. Each chart object contains a `series` property which is an array containing the data for each of the series the chart renders. A `data` property exists within each series containing all the data within, and the `name` property contains the name of the series.

For example:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].name
-> "APPL"
```

```js
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data
-> Array[1774]
```

HighCharts' documentation is laid out in the same format as the JavaScript object it creates. This can be viewed here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts.

Comment: [james-donnelly] provided the way to access the data series, the question is how do we extract the data from the chart ?

Comment: @prgbenz the data series is an array of points on the chart. You can simply iterate through each point to extract the information you need.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly  thanks !   But the data is displayable but no accessible because the author and I are trying to extract the data out from the chart. can I hack the .js ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you download the page with the chart, you can easily extract the data. It will be stocked in the main *.html file.

It's not the actual data, but rather the positions of every point in the chart. But you'll just have to scale it to get what you want.