# How to format Hightcharts charts data in python?

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts

I have the following chart:
[image: Sales for Jabra elite 65t using Helium10]
I would like the data in a csv file, preferably using python, but I am not familiar with JS.

The source of the data is a tool called Helium10, which is a free Chrome extension to get insights into Amazon data. It's totally legal. The charts show number of items sold on a given day. Here's my URL: https://members.helium10.com/black-box

For the first data point for date Jun 11, this is the data:

```
<path fill="none" class="highcharts-crosshair highcharts-crosshair-thin 
undefined" stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="1" style="pointer-events:none;" 
visibility="hidden" d="M 63.5 10 L 63.5 326"></path>
```

For visible chart this is the data:

```
<path fill="none" d="M 0 301.99066666666664 C 0 301.99066666666664 96.72 
275.6994666666667 161.2 224.14933333333335 C 225.67999999999998 172.5992 257.91999999999996 44.24000000000001 322.4 44.24000000000001 C 386.88 
44.24000000000001 419.12000000000006 197.60533333333336 483.6 
197.60533333333336 C 548.08 197.60533333333336 580.3199999999999 
29.072000000000003 644.8 29.072000000000003 C 709.28 29.072000000000003 
741.52 62.04133333333334 806 62.04133333333334 C 870.4799999999999 
62.04133333333334 967.2 23.48933333333332 967.2 23.48933333333332" 
class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="2" stroke-
linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
```

and this right below:

```
<path fill="none" d="M -10 301.99066666666664 L 0 301.99066666666664 C 0 
301.99066666666664 96.72 275.6994666666667 161.2 224.14933333333335 C 
225.67999999999998 172.5992 257.91999999999996 44.24000000000001 322.4 
44.24000000000001 C 386.88 44.24000000000001 419.12000000000006 
197.60533333333336 483.6 197.60533333333336 C 548.08 197.60533333333336 
580.3199999999999 29.072000000000003 644.8 29.072000000000003 C 709.28 
29.072000000000003 741.52 62.04133333333334 806 62.04133333333334 C 
870.4799999999999 62.04133333333334 967.2 23.48933333333332 967.2 
23.48933333333332 L 977.2 23.48933333333332" stroke-linejoin="round" 
visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" 
class="highcharts-tracker"></path>
```

I not sure how these numbers are calculated as data points? And using python, how I could scrape these Highcharts. I've seen multiple examples on SO of others that have done it, but none of their codes are working anymore.

Other examples: 
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971406/scrape-highcharts-data-to-csv-file)
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147250/how-to-extract-the-data-from-highstock-chart)

Let me know if I need to clarify stuff.

Comment: I tried to format the long numbers using https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.phpbut they don't correlate with the dates shown in the graph

Comment: Hi @doomdaam, The chart data should be available in the global scope by `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points`. However, that paths are calculated based on axis value, you can revert that caclulation by using `toValue` method: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue

Comment: That's javascript right, I'm not sure how to translate that to pythonic.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not help you with python.